# Get maximum and minimum theoretical output from xgboost classifier

Tags: python, xgboost

Assume I have a trained XGBClassifier object (the sklearn interface). How could I determine what is the highest possible output the model could provide, in terms of the output from model.predict_proba(input)[:,1]? That is, the probability of the class 1 in a binary classification problem.

Of course, I know the max predicted value found in my training data. However, given unseen data, I assume that there could be higher values, because of the high number of possible traversal paths on every tree that XGBoost constructed.

So how could I come up with an answer to this using Python?

What I've tried so far was basically to determine the min and max values of every feature I had in training data (which were all continuous, possibly containing np.nans) and use scipy.optimize.minimize, specifying the min/max bounds for every feature. My "cost" function would simply be the model predict_proba. Also, to account for the np.nans, I used a placeholder (-1) and made the search space account for that.

This was not successful at all. All methods I've tried gave different answers, and all of them were equal or lower than my known max value in training data.

Code I used, simplified:

```py
minmax = {feature: {'min': df[feature].min(), 'max': df[feature].max()} for feature in features}

md = joblib.load('my_xgboost_model.joblib')

def cost(x):
    x[x < 0] = np.nan

    cst =  md.predict_proba(np.array([x]))[:, 1]

    return -float(cst[0])

# random initial guess
x0 = np.random.randn(22)
x0[x0 <= -1] = -0.5
opt = minimize(
    cost,
    x0 = x0,
    method='Nelder-Mead',
    tol=1e-15,
    bounds=[(-1, v['max']) for k, v in minmax.items()]
)
```

Comment: The max. probability of an "event" should approach `1` in the binary classification case? Do you have a reason to think that this isn't so in your dataset?

Comment: Also, if the max. probability is expected to be a lot less than `1`, then perhaps you should use a different objective function? For example, `binary:logitraw` instead of `binary`?

Answer (score 1):

There are potentially as many unique outputs as the product of the numbers of leaves in each tree, so an exhaustive check is probably not feasible except for small models.

The output function is piecewise constant, and often highly nonlinear, and often highly overfit, so it's not surprising that a traditional optimization approach doesn't find the extrema.

An easy lower and upper bound are obtained by taking the minimum and maximum leaf score from every tree and summing them (with learning rate scaling that result, and adding the base score of applicable, then applying a link function if applicable). But this isn't necessarily achieved: the feature space for the minimum leaf of one tree might not overlap with that of another tree. But I think this is a good start, and if the bound equals any of your training predictions, you're done. And perhaps you can perform some kind of search among nearly-extremal leaves?

I put that together in a [quick colab notebook](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/SE77827945_xgb_min_max_pred.ipynb).  I'm unable to construct an example where the theoretical min & max aren't achieved by some training row, using the breast cancer dataset in sklearn.  If anyone wants to play around with it, let me know (make a PR?) if you manage a difference!

Comment: You're right. I actually tried to formulate an exhaustive search according to https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3334#issuecomment-390864251, but that would result (in my case) in 188^22 possibilities, which would take literally years. I'm not sure I understood your idea about the min and max leaf score from each tree. Could you explain it in more detail? Thank you so much.

Comment: The largest possible prediction would go through all the trees and end up in leaves with the largest score (since leaf scores are what are getting summed to make the final prediction). That might not be achievable: e.g., if the largest leaf score in tree 1 occurs down the left branch of the tree defined by the split at the root feature_1<0, but the largest leaf score in tree 2 occurs down the right branch of the tree with feature_1>5. // I added a colab notebook with the calculations. Interestingly, I can't yet create a model where these theoretical bounds aren't realized by a training row.