Finding the maximum value from a Random Forest Regression model in python
I've been using random forest regression to calculate the Return On Ad Spend (ROAS) when the user gives the upper bound. My model takes in three input variables: the cost of TV, Radio and Newspaper ads. However, to find the most optimal value, I need to use a for loop to iterate through every dollar, which is time-consuming. Is there a faster method to find the highest y value in my program?
def ROASPrediction(Q,TV,Radio,Newspaper):
    rec = "Recommended Investment for Best Sales"
    y_big = 0
    x_b = 0
    y_b = 0
    z_b = 0
    for x in range(TV // 2, TV):
        for y in range(Radio // 2, Radio):
            for z in range(Newspaper // 2, Newspaper):
                customer_features = np.array([x, y, z])
                customer_features1 = customer_features.reshape(1, -1)
                # customer_features1 =pd.DataFrame(customer_features)
                model_fit1 = joblib.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/ROAS.joblib')
                y_future_pred = model_fit1.predict(customer_features1)
                print("y_future_pred", y_future_pred)
                if (y_future_pred[0] >= y_big):
                    y_big = y_future_pred[0]
                    x_b = x
                    y_b = y
                    z_b = z
    # y_future_pred1= str(y_future_pred[0]) + "M$"
    # y_roas= y_future_pred[0]*1000000 / (TV+Radio+Newspaper)
    y_future_pred1 = str(y_big) + "M$"
    y_roas = y_big * 1000000 / (TV + Radio + Newspaper)
    x_b1 = str(x_b)
    y_b1 = str(y_b)
    z_b1 = str(z_b)
    y_roas1 = str(y_roas) + "%"
    return rec, x_b1, y_b1, z_b1, y_future_pred1, y_roas1

And the following code is my Random Forest Model.
df = pd.read_csv('/Advertising.csv')
df.head()
x = df[['TV', 'Radio','Newspaper']]
y = df[['Sales']]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (x, y, test_size=0.20 , random_state=41)
rf_regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
rf_regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = rf_regressor.predict(x_test)

And this is the csv file I'm using.
Is there any way to make the ROASPrediction function more efficient so that it does not take like 5 minutes to compute just $30 of TV, Radio and Newspaper?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/77827945/10495893 asks this question but for xgboost, but I don't think there's a significant difference for this purpose?

Does this answer your question? Get maximum and minimum theoretical output from xgboost classifier

@BenReiniger I was able to find a solution, and I had to just use meshgrid instead of the for loop, so what I've learnt is that I should just read the docs coz there are probably functions that do the things that you want in the modules you use
